# How to get monitor size

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my project I need to determine the size of the monitor/screen. I can get the screen resolution using following code

```
   X = fPixelsToTwips(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), "X") '
   Y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)
```

This gives me the correct screen resolution. But I have a 13.6" laptop screen and my friend has 15.6" laptop screen. Both has same screen resolution 1366*768. But the screen size is different. So how can I determine screen size of monitor? This is very important for my project.

Comment: If all else fails, you could ask the user for the screen size. I know it's not ideal.  zedfoxus might be onto something though. Good luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can tap into WMI's `WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams` to get some information about your display. I was successfully able to display the diagonal length of both displays with this code using Windows 7.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim WMIObject As Object
    Dim WMIResult As Object
    Dim WMIItem As Object

    Set WMIObject = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\WMI")
    Set WMIResult = WMIObject.ExecQuery("Select * From WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams")

    Dim Diagonal As Double
    Dim Width As Double
    Dim Height As Double
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Counter = 1

    For Each WMIItem In WMIResult

        Width = WMIItem.MaxHorizontalImageSize / 2.54
        Height = WMIItem.MaxVerticalImageSize / 2.54
        Diagonal = Sqr((Height ^ 2) + (Width ^ 2))

        MsgBox "Your monitor # " & Counter & " is approximiately " & Round(Diagonal, 2) & " inches diagonal"
        Counter = Counter + 1

    Next

End Sub
```

Some other references that may help you.

- [VBScript and WMI to capture display information](http://www.activexperts.com/admin/scripts/wmiscripts/vbscript/0066/)
- [PowerShell and WMI to capture display information](http://www.activexperts.com/admin/scripts/wmiscripts/powershell/0066/)
- [C# to capture display information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911553/how-can-i-get-the-real-size-of-the-lcd-display-diagonal-i-e-if-a-it-is-a-17)
- [System Information using VBA and WMI](https://sites.google.com/site/beyondexcel/project-updates/exposingsystemsecretswithvbaandwmiapi)

Comment: @MatthewD it is indeed quite interesting to see all the kinds of information WMI exposes. I didn't know this was possible until trying it myself after some Googling

Comment: I went down a different path from my Googling. I will put this info in my "bag of tricks". Thanks.

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have two monitor, is there any way to check on which monitor my project is currently running?

Comment: @user1670773 I am sure there is a way to do that, but I don't know the answer. You might benefit from creating a new question so that someone more knowledgeable than me can help out

Comment: Note that, as noted in the Wmi documentation, the actual values may not be available.